# Parameterize a quoted string in Python's SQL DBI

Tags: python, postgresql, python-db-api, pg8000

I am using `pg8000` to connect to a PostgreSQL database via Python. I would like to be able to send in dates as parameters via the `cursor.execute` method:

```
def info_by_month(cursor, year, month):
    query = """
    SELECT *
    FROM info
    WHERE date_trunc('month', info.created_at) =
          date_trunc('month', '%s-%s-01')
    """
    cursor.execute(query, (year, month))
    return cursor
```

This will raise the error: `InterfaceError: '%s' not supported in a quoted string within the query string`. It's possible to use Python's string formatting to insert the date in there. The use of the string formatting mini language provides a measure of data validation to prevent SQL injection attacks, but it's still pretty ugly.

```
def info_by_month(cursor, year, month):
    query = """
    SELECT *
    FROM info
    WHERE date_trunc('month', info.created_at) =
          date_trunc('month', '{:04}-{:02}-01')
    """.format(year, month)
    cursor.execute(query)
    return cursor
```

How do I sent a quoted string into the `cursor.execute` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the `format` ahead of time, and then pass the resulting string into `execute`. That way you avoid the *SQL injection* potential, but still get the formatting you want.

e.g. the query becomes:

```
query = """
    SELECT *
    FROM info
    WHERE date_trunc('month', info.created_at) =
          date_trunc('month', %s)"""
```

And then the `format` and `execute` becomes:

```
dateStr = "{:04}-{:02}-01".format(year, month)
cursor.execute(query, dateStr)
```

I use *psycopg2*, but it appears *pg8000* adheres to the same *DBI* standard, so I would expect this to work in *pg8000*, too.

Comment: FYI that's what I mention in the second code snippet. I was wondering ig it's possible to improve on that further.

Comment: My code is actually different than your 2nd snippet. In your 2nd snippet, you're doing the `format` and then passing the whole string to `execute`. That means you aren't having the *SQL* library do any of the interpolation. In my example, I am doing the `format`, and then passing it as an argument to `execute`, where the *SQL* library then can do interpolation as needed, averting potential *SQL injection*. Basically, my code snippet is the answer your your question **"How do I sent a quoted string into the cursor.execute method?"**

Comment: Marking as correct because it's more sensible than anything I can think of!

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do this via concatenation, to the detriment of readability.

```
query = """
  SELECT *
  FROM info
  WHERE date_trunc('month', info.created_at) =
        date_trunc('month', %s || '-' || %s || '-01')
"""
cursor.execute(query, (year, month))
```

Comment: I would submit that my style of code is more readable, but I suppose that may be a personal preference...

Comment: Agreed. Added it only for the sake of completeness of record. Thanks again for taking the time to answer.